# Processing termination of activated Application Host after creation of Service Fabric application

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateless

We have roughly 12 Service Fabric clusters running in Azure.  They are running correctly in both our Production and Test environments.  We have found recently that one of them will not start locally.  We have not ran this one locally in quite a while, and I am having a hard time tracking down what might have happened that is causing this error.  It is happening on any machine I try to run locally on.

Specifically, after the type is registered, and the app created, the host process immediately terminates:

"Message": "EventName: ApplicationProcessExited Category: StateTransition EventInstanceId 158f38d1-47ac-4b70-9830-0d8d3cdf8f9c ApplicationName fabric:/Office.Ocv.CustomerTalkback.AutomatedService.ServiceFabric Application terminated, ServiceName=fabric:/Office.Ocv.CustomerTalkback.AutomatedService.ServiceFabric/MS.Internal.Office.Ocv.Services.CustomerTalkback.Automated, ServicePackageName=MS.Internal.Office.Ocv.Services.CustomerTalkback.Automated.Package, ServicePackageActivationId=d58e53d1-af22-42fb-9003-3154bcb8d00b, IsExclusive=True, CodePackageName=Code, EntryPointType=Exe, ExeName=MS.Internal.Office.Ocv.Services.CustomerTalkback.Automated.exe, ProcessId=16756, HostId=e27ccd9d-cff6-4317-b168-5a4b7b724808, ExitCode=2147516563, UnexpectedTermination=True, StartTime=06/18/2019 15:47:26. ",

This is dotnet core 2.2.0.  All of our Service Fabric apps are running with the same settings/dependencies, etc.  Only this one fails locally.

I have tried moving the local cluster to a larger drive (800 GB free); deploying manually via PowerShell (usually VS 2019).

Any help (even if it is just a suggestion of trouble shooting steps) would be much appreciated as I have working on this for about 16 hours over last three days.

thanks!

Comment: Could be the app itself is failing during the startup fase. Extend your logging, [catch errors during startup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2#startup-exception-handling) and spit through the logs. It might be missing a dependency while running locally.

Comment: Uhm, Behuler? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I had was with the full name of the assembly.  The local path was short (like d:\src\adm), but the full assembly name was ~65 characters.  It appears as though the PowerShell that deploys locally would fail silently on this.  When I dropped the length of the name down to about 35 characters it started working.